what can make adamw with lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau to cause hallucination while with adam alone and a fixed lr there is much less hallucination?
I am currently working on an image-to-image task and have observed that when using the AdamW optimizer with a learning rate scheduler (ReduceLROnPlateau), the performance of the model degrades significantly. In contrast, using the Adam optimizer with a fixed learning rate yields much better results. Despite experimenting with various hyperparameters for AdamW and the scheduler, I have been unable to achieve performance comparable to that of the Adam optimizer with a fixed learning rate. I am seeking a mathematical explanation for this phenomenon (I think it might not be easy to provide a math solution, even just a general explanation of math will  enough) or at least an answer that can provide insight into why it occurs.
well I suspected the lr scheduler but it set on changing when there is no improvement on the loss value. This might seem crazy but I suspected maybe I am calculating loss incorrectly but it is correct. I am thinking mayve both adamw and lr scheduler have their strategies to change lr maybe the combination in this specific task cannot converge to an acceptable solution.
this is the code part:
optimizerG = torch.optim.AdamW(netG.parameters(), lr=1e-3, betas=(0.5, 0.999), weight_decay=1e-6)
schedulerG = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizerG, mode='min', factor=0.1, patience=5)

